# How to use Data.Argonaut.Decode module with JSON with any field?

Tags: purescript

I know if I have JSON with specific known fields, like "date" and "title"

```
{
  "date": "any string",
  "title": "any string"
}
```

Then, I can decode it by defining

```
myDecodeFunc :: Json -> Either JsonDecodeError ({ date :: String, title :: String })

myDecodeFunc = decodeJson
```

However, I can't seem to find how to decode the same JSON with arbitrary fields like this.

```
{
  "any field": "any string",
  "any field": "any string"
}
```

I am new to Purescript, so any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fancy term for a "record"-ish thing where you don't know all possible fields in advance is *dictionary*.

And to parse JSON as a dictionary, use a dictionary-ish type, such as [`Foreign.Object`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-foreign-object/3.0.0/docs/Foreign.Object#t:Object) for example, which just happens to have a handy instance of `FromJSON`:

```
import Foreign.Object (Object)

myDecodeFunc :: Json -> Either JsonDecodeError (Object String)
myDecodeFunc = decodeJson
```